# Como instalar o nodemon globalmente?

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando instalar o `nodemon` globalmente, usando:

```
npm install nodemon --global
```

Ele parece instalar normalmente, com dois avisos para um módulo opcional:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0
```

Porém quando tento executá-lo:

```
nodemon servidor.js
```

Dá erro:

```
'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

> O que há de errado?

*P.S. em outro computador funcionou sem problemas. Estou num Windows 10.*

Comment: Será que instalaste com um user e agora estás com outro? Que sistema operativo usas? Por exemplo se fazes `install -g nodemon` como `sudo` ele instala numa diretoria que não é comum a outros utilizadores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em algumas instalações do **node**, o [prefixo](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prefix) não é atribuído no **caminho** das variáveis do ambiente, então o que você instalar **globalmente** não funcionar como o esperado. Para resolver isso, temos que adicionar o **prefixo** no **caminho** das variáveis do ambiente. Isso pode ser feito pelo **prompt de comando**.

> Para fazer isso, primeiro é necessário descobrir qual é o caminho do prefixo, isso pode ser resolvido fazendo assim:

`npm config get prefix`

> O comando vai resultar em um caminho, copie-o e cole no próximo comando:

`set PATH=%PATH%;caminho;`

> Demonstração

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Para complementar a resposta do @Luc, no Windows 10, a configuração acima não persistiu - e eu resolvi colocando manualmente no `Path` das `variáveis de usuário` (não nas de sistema):

[image: variáveis de usuário; path selecionado]

No `Path`, eu incluí o endereço `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E depois de um `reboot`, finalmente a configuração persistiu.

Answer (score -1):

Você deve rodar com o seguinte comando:

```
npm nodemon servidor.js
```